# In what scenario the framework should not be used?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I have the first meeting with my project manager and she assigned me a project which to be start soon. She explained to me few points related project e.g. technology, functionality, end user expectation etc.

- MVC based web application
- Not to use any framework
- `Server Side` : use only `Java, servlet, jsp`
- `UI :` `Javascript, jQuery` can also be used
- integratation with existing project (at later stage)

There is one point i can not understand why she asked me to not to use any framework although i could not ask why. Does anybody clarify ? If i use any framework like spring then will it create any problem while integration with existing project.

Comment: Servlet and JSP are already frameworks. You can perfectly implement MVC with just that: your model are Java objects, you views are JSP, your controller are Servlet. You don't necessary need more at first.

Answer (score 8):

I can recognize 2 sub questions in your question.

1. In what scenario the framework should not be used?
2. why she asked me to not to use any framework?

Answer 1

I can imagine situation when you don't need any framework. It is if you have to create extremely simple 1-2 screen application without any security, access rules and probably without DB based persistence. This means that IMHO framework-less application is good as a student exercise just to understand how things work.

Answer 2

She is ... not professional enough. I am sorry to say it but this is pretty obvious. To implement MVC without framework you have to perform a lot of dirty work. I believe that the key reason for this strange requirement is "integratation with existing project" that is probably created without any framework, so PM thinks that framework could bother you during this integration.

Moreover, product manager should *never* dictate R&D how to implement project. Project manager can *politely* ask to implement certain set of features.

I am sorry if my answer is helpful.

Comment: +1 for *I am sorry if my answer is helpful*:)

Comment: Alex, Thank you for your time. Well i can't comment over her professionalism but i think she has almost 10 years of industry experience.

Comment: @user1010399, please accept my condolences. Professionalism is not always a function of years in field. She has almost 10 years of experience? And I have almost 20 years of experience. So what? I just expressed my opinion. Try to ask what the reasons are. Probably they exist (although I do not believe in this).

Comment: All due respect, this mentiality deserves a fat -1 for the simple reason of keeping Stack Overflow attractive for non-constructive questions which doesn't belong at Stack Overflow in first place. Just do not post answers to non-constructive questions. If you can't resist it, look for a discussion forum.